# Using Order By in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-order-by

This is my normal mysql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item order by ";
if(my_condition)
{
       $sql. = "FIELD(`category`, 'Auto & Accessories', 'Couch', 'Bed', 
       'Desk &     Office', 'Bike &            Scooter', 'Tools', 'Leisure', 
        'Iron & Wood', 'Cabinet', 'Kitchen & Accessories', 'Refrigerator & Appliances',
        'Toys & Games', 'Chair', 'Table', 'Garden & Terrace', 'TV, HIFI & Computers', 
        'General Item')";

}
else
{
     $sql .= "category asc";
}
```

I need it in CI in active record. I tried in following way:

```
      if(my_condition)
            {
                $this->db->order_by("FIELD(`category`, 'Auto & Accessories', 'Couch',
                'Bed', 'Desk & Office', 'Bike & Scooter', 'Tools', 'Leisure', 'Iron & 
                 Wood', 'Cabinet', 'Kitchen & Accessories', 'Refrigerator & 
                 Appliances', 'Toys & Games', 'Chair', 'Table', 'Garden & Terrace', 
                 'TV, HIFI & Computers', 'General Item')");

            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->order_by("category", "asc");
            }
```

But, I got this error::

```
   Error Number: 1064
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your           
   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Couch'`, `'Bed'`, `'Desk` &  
   Office', `'Bike` & Scooter', `'Tools'`, `'Leisure'`,' at line 6


  Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\straatjutter_service\system\database\DB_driver.php

 Line Number: 330
```

How to solve it? Actually I need my item's category sorted in above format. This can be done in normal mysql query. But, get confused in doing it in active records.

Comment: It seems to be correct. Trying removing the tildes before and after the column name.

Comment: omfkg is this a db field name *Toys & Games* ???

Comment: I was thinking the same

Comment: @verisimilitude, you mean removing ` from `category`?? I did that and got same error. Even I did 'category' also, but got the above error!

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick, nope, category is only db field name and others are field values. That is, 'Auto & Accessories', 'Couch',
                'Bed', 'Desk & Office', 'Bike & Scooter', 'Tools', 'Leisure', 'Iron & 
                 Wood', 'Cabinet', 'Kitchen & Accessories', 'Refrigerator & 
                 Appliances', 'Toys & Games', 'Chair', 'Table', 'Garden & Terrace', 
                 'TV, HIFI & Computers', 'General Item' are field values of category field.

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick: How can they be DB field names?

Comment: @verisimilitude indeed

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick: The OP wants to enforce a custom order for the returned result set. Look up MySQL's `Field` function and check how it is used for this purpose.

Comment: P.s. It isn't active record. Just a query builder.

Comment: @verisimilitude yep it sounds new to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this::

```
            $this->db->select('i.id, condition, description, created_at, updated_at, category, latitude, longitude, status, d.device_token, d.facebook, d.preferred, d.email, d.phone');
            $this->db->select("CONCAT('$url', `image_url_original`) AS `image_url_original`", false);
            $this->db->select("CONCAT('$url', `image_url_mid`) AS `image_url_mid`", false);
            $this->db->select("CONCAT('$url', `image_url_thumb`) AS `image_url_thumb`", false);
            $this->db->select("FIELD(`category`, 'Auto & Accessories', 'Couch', 'Bed', 'Desk & Office', 'Bike & Scooter', 'Tools', 'Leisure', 'Iron & Wood', 'Cabinet', 'Kitchen & Accessories', 'Refrigerator & Appliances', 'Toys & Games', 'Chair', 'Table', 'Garden & Terrace', 'TV, HIFI & Computers', 'General Item') AS `sort_col`", false);

            $this->db->from('item as i');
            $this->db->join('device as d', 'i.device_id = d.device_token');

            $this->db->where('created_at > DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');
            $this->db->where('i.status', 'shared');

            if($language === 'nl_NL') {
                $this->db->order_by('sort_col', 'asc');
            } else {
                $this->db->order_by('category', 'asc');
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use this way

```
$ids = "1,3,2,4";
$qry ="SELECT * FROM (`destination`) WHERE `id` IN ($ids) ORDER BY `FIELD` ( id, $ids )";
$result = $this->db->query($qry);
return $result->result();
```

Comment: `$ids = 1,3,2,4` is not valid php.

Comment: what I ment is $ids = "1,3,2,4";