# Get rows sorted by a particular column in Codeigniter using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and have some data in my database like this:

```
id   name    priority

1    Amit      3
2    Pankaj    2
3    Ashish    5
```

Now I want to retrieve data in this format, sorted by priority :

```
id   name    priority

1    Pankaj    2
2    Amit      3
3    Ashish    5
```

I was trying this code but it didn't work:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('class')->order_by('priority', 'desc');
```

Comment: if order by priority in descending, then `Ashish` should come first. What say?

Comment: I think you want to order by priority "ASC", no ?

Comment: but Amit position is same.

Comment: And please tell us what you mean by "didn't work"

Comment: Please take time to explain your problem properly.

Comment: this should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585979/using-order-by-in-codeigniter

Comment: @user3653474 working yet?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get you data like the second one you need to us ASC and return `result_array()`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Working Image

[image]

**As shown in model below:**

**File-name:** Model_sample.php

```
<?php

class Model_sample extends CI_Model {

    public function get_data() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'class');
        $this->db->order_by('priority', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

**File-name:** Welcome.php

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('model_sample');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['results'] = array();

        $data['results'] = $this->model_sample->get_data();

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

**View**

**File-name:** welcome_message.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Class ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Priority</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if ($results) {?>
        <?php foreach ($results as $result) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['priority'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
        <?php } else {?>
            <tr>
                <td>No Results</td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Model add this

```
$query = $this->db->query->("SELECT * FROM class ORDER BY priority DESC")
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```