# rearrange the array according to specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am trying to fetch values from database through the following code

```
public function get_value($userid)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("users");
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $r1 = $query->result();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($r1);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I get the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [fullname] => user 3               
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [fullname] => User 4                
        )
     [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [fullname] => User 5                
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [fullname] => User 6                
        )
)
```

I wish to rearrange the array in a way that if "$userid" matches the "id" in the array then that value should be at the first position

> e.g if $userid = 5, then the array should be like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [fullname] => User 5                
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [fullname] => user 3               
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [fullname] => User 4                
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [fullname] => User 6                
        )
)
```

Can anyone please tell how to do so

Comment: use where condition

Comment: it doesn't look like your results are `id` `desc`

Comment: @mickmackusa its just a sample to give an idea of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check from "order by field" i think. Something like :

```
select * from users order by field(id,5) desc, id desc
```

It will sort first by field first and then by id desc. You don't need to put every values in field(id,?,?,?...), you only need to put the one you want `field(id,5)`

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/

In your case this should look like :

```
$this->db->order_by("field(id,".$userid.")", "desc");
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
```

Comment: Simplest Way To Do. Well Done @Pierre

Comment: @Pierre Granger it seems to be great , but i am syntax error which i am not able to resolve

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is ? is it a sql error or php ?

Comment: @Pierre Granger I got this error:     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, 5) DESC, `id` DESC' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY field(id DESC, 5) DESC, `id` DESC

Comment: You have an unwanted  "desc" in field(id,5) :
`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY field(id DESC, 5) DESC, id DESC`
Should be :
`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY field(id, 5) DESC, id DESC`

Comment: @Pierre Granger yeah thats true, but in code i am not able to form a query where it gets removed, if i remove desc from query then i am getting values in asc order, but i want it to be desc

Comment: Sorry i'm not familiar with this kind of syntaxes :( Doesn't `$this->db->order_by("field(id,".$userid.")", "desc");` works ?

Comment: Well too bad i don't know the syntaxes of your $this->db :( what is it ? codeigniter ? I found out things like this but have no idea if this is where your problem came from... `$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
$this -> db -> order_by('FIELD(id, 3,1,2)');`

For me the problem here is just that we can't manage to put the correct syntax to your $this->db, we need in the end field(id,5) desc, but you can only render field(id desc,5) desc, and the first desc is undesirable :(

Comment: No issues, it gave me the main idea how to do it, thanks

Comment: Just for my personal culture, what is your $this->db ? Is it from codeigniter ?

Comment: @Pierre Granger yes it is

Comment: So you can take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585979/using-order-by-in-codeigniter 

`$this->db->select("FIELD(`id`,".$userid.") as sort_col",false) ;`
`$this->db->order_by('sort_col', 'desc');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usort($r1, function (stdClass $a, stdClass $b) use ($userid) {
    if ($a->id == $userid) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ($b->id == $userid) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/835568)**.

```
array_merge(
  array_filter($array, function($v) use($userid) {return $v->id == $userid;}),
  array_filter($array, function($v) use($userid) {return $v->id != $userid;})
)
```